# Get array values to display inside an object in a @foreach loop using Laravel Blade

Tags: php, laravel

In a blade template, I have:

```
@foreach($users as $user)
 {{ $user->id }}  // this displays just fine, the number 1
 {{ $weeklyCallsArray{$user->id} }} // get "Undefined offset:" error
 {{ $weeklyCallsArray{1} }} // this works fine
@endforeach
```

How can I get the array to display with the corresponding user? I want to use something like:

```
$weeklyCallsArray{user->id}
```

Here is my query and return in the controller:

```
$users = DB::table('users')->get();
foreach ($users as $user) {
    $userId = $user->id;
    $countThisWeek = DB::table('calls')
        ->where('called_by', '=', $userId)
        ->where('calledd_on', '>=', Carbon::now()->startOfWeek())
        ->count();
    $weeklyCallArray[$userId] = $countThisWeek;
}

return view('users')
    ->with(['users' => $users])
    ->with(['weeklyCallsArray' => $weeklyCallsArray]);
```

Comment: Could you be missing $ sign on the user variable in your foreach?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo for the question, updated it, I also double checked and I do get the error using $user->id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using arrays wrong in the view?  I've never seen that syntax before.

```
$weeklyCallsArray[$user->id]
```

Comment: I could of swore I tried that and it didn't work... but I tried it again and it works great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should use eloquent and you can load calls of the user with the user.

```
$users = User::with(['calls' => function($q){
     $q->calledd_on >= Carbon::now()->startOfWeek());
}]->whereUserId($id)->get();
```

Then in your view you can count the calls like this:

```
@foreach($users as $user)
   {{ $user->id }}
   {{ count($user->calls) }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I think it had some syntax errors but I almost have it working. This looks like the ideal way to get it done.